# Indirect Object vs Object of preposition

Tags: indirect-objects

> 1. The principal gave Martha an award.
> 2. The principal gave an award to Martha.

Many grammar sites (e.g. [www.k12reader.com](https://www.k12reader.com/term/indirect-object/))  say that Martha in the first sentence is an Indirect Object and Martha in the second sentence is an object of preposition.

If it is so, **to Martha** in the second sentence is a prepositional phrase. Then, my question is: **what function does this prepositional phrase do in the sentence?**

Comment: It is a complement of the verb _gave_: its function is identical to _Martha_ in the first sentence. I would still call it an indirect object.

Comment: @ColinFine, do you mean it takes a double role - the Indirect Object of the verb *gave* and the object of the preposition *to*?

Comment: In your second example the preposition phrase "to Martha" functions not as indirect object but as **complement** of "gave".

Comment: @BillJ thank you. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: J Lawler states on [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/601512/placement-of-objects-after-a-verb/601520?noredirect=1#comment1515826_601520): ' "Indirect object" is an ill-defined term in English grammar ...' Different grammars (forget dictionaries!) use conflicting definitions. People tend to quote extracts from their favoured grammars as if there were a consensus on metalanguage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [1] *The principal gave Martha an award*.
>
> [2] *The principal gave an award to Martha*.

In [1] "Martha" is related directly to the verb "gave" and thus is the indirect object.

But in [2] "Martha" is related to the verb only indirectly, via the preposition "to", and thus is not an indirect object of the verb, but the object of the preposition "to". The PP "to Martha" functions as **complement** of "gave".